# Returning a value on class access in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

For example, the String class returns a value upon you accessing it.  I.e.

`x = "hello world"`

Now, if you were to write a method like so,

```
def getstr
  x
end
```

This would return the string "hello world"

How can I do this for other classes? For example, I have a wrapper class for TCPSocket and upon accessing the instance of my Manager class I want it to return the classes TCPSocket instance i.e.

```
sock = Manager.new
sock
```

I want the second line `sock` to return my TCPSocket instance.  I don't want to actually access any method, i..e, **I do not want this:**

```
sock = Manager.new
sock.getsocket ...
```

I've tried creating a method for self, but this doesn't work the way I want it to, because I have to access the method like so: class.self

Comment: Off-topic, just for info: PHP has the so called "magic method" [`__toString()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) for that. If a class implements this method, it's instances can be used as strings (in a string context). This is a nice feature, but it seems that there is nothing comparable in ruby.. (I'm a ruby noob ;)

Comment: Ah, I was hoping Ruby had something like that, except where I can make it return any kind of value upon access to the class alone (i.e. $kls returns some value, but $kls->method() still calls said kls methods), but for Ruby

Comment: How are you supposed to get to your object then?

Comment: Wait, so you want to set `sock` to an instance of `Manager`, but have it actually be something other than what you just set it to? -_- Also, I don't see how your example with `String` makes any sense. First of all, it's false (try it in IRB, methods aren't closures so that doesn't actually work), and for another, I don't see how it relates to your second example with `Manager`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a string literal. It's part of the language. You can't define that sort of thing within Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

If the Manager class is controlled by you, you can override the new class method and return whatever object you need. So your need should become like this.

```
classs Manager

  def self.new
    super
    TCPSocket.new
  end
end
```

So, when you call

```
manager = Manager.new
```

it should return an TCPSocket instance.
Try this, still you need help please let me know, thank you.

Comment: This answer will work if you replace `initialize` with `self.new`.

Comment: This won't work. The return value of initialize is ignored, and it returns always an instance of it's own class (an instance of `Manager` in this case).

Comment: sorry, i have updated the answer like overriding class method 'new'.

Comment: I was actually referring to being able to get the TCPSocket instance after the object is created.  I.e., like some kind of default accessor where the instance of the class returns the TCPSocket object, but I am able to still call the methods of my class.  (I.e., exactly like the String class)

Comment: Yes, now you dont want to call any method to return TCPSocket instance. When you provide Manager.new => returns TCPSocket class instance.

Comment: Yes, but that won't work with the design of my Manager class, since I want to access these objects after they are created.  However, I decided to "bite" the bullet and just add in an accessor for the TCPSocket instance.  (i.e. manager.sock instead of manager)

Comment: What do you need class for? If you need namespace use `module`. Your newly created object will be garbage collected immediately as there is no reference to it.